# prevent split of words containing - with keras ootb text_to_word_sequence

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp

I am using:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

text = 'Decreased glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase activity along with oxidative stress affects visual contrast sensitivity in alcoholics.'

words = set(text_to_word_sequence(text))

print(words)
```

which results in:

```
{'oxidative', 'contrast', '6', 'affects', 'in', 'dehydrogenase', 'visual', 'stress', 'glucose', 'phosphate', 'along', 'activity', 'with', 'alcoholics', 'decreased', 'sensitivity'}
```

Is there a way to prevent the splitting of the word: glucose-6-phosphate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by removing the hyphen from the `filters` argument:

```
from keras_preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

text = 'Decreased glucose-6-phosphate ...'

words = set(text_to_word_sequence(text,
 filters='!"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n'))
words

{'activity',
 'affects',
 'alcoholics',
 'along',
 'contrast',
 'decreased',
 'dehydrogenase',
 'glucose-6-phosphate',
 'in',
 'oxidative',
 'sensitivity',
 'stress',
 'visual',
 'with'}
```

This will of course affect any word in your text that contains a hyphen.